# This is my code to show youtube video details with PHP, but it is not working. Web page is blank

Tags: php, youtube

This is my code to show YouTube video details, but it is not working. The web page is blank. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$json_output = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/aNgnkIvLdpU?v=2&alt=json");
$json = json_decode($json_output, true);

//This gives you the video description
$video_description = $json['entry']['media$group']['media$description']['$t'];

//This gives you the video views count
$view_count = $json['entry']['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];

//This gives you the video title
$video_title = $json['entry']['title']['$t'];

echo $video_title;

echo $view_count;

echo $video_description; 
?>
```

Comment: web page is blank => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and what does HTML source reveal? code or **parsed** code?

Comment: *"but it is not working"* - Can you define "not working"?

Comment: You didn't have to post that Smokey @RiggsFolly there's already an "answer" below ;-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I was being "sarcastic" lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well we had better give the guy a UV

Comment: @RiggsFolly *cough*.... you're either trying to be funny, and/or being what I was earlier ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yup, tick either of the above

Comment: **A:** That video does **NOT** exist. There, now go away or @RiggsFolly will *poof!* you into oblivion.

Comment: @RiggsFolly and pass it on to my dog? *Nope, fat chance 'o that*. He's got fleas and quite happy not having anything else to move in on their territory. Ticks are evil depending on.... "what" tick to tick ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This URL is not working:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/aNgnkIvLdpU?v=2&alt=json): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 410 Gone
```

Comment: yeah, I know that too and was going to post it as a "comment".